# Manipulate pieces of data in an html fragment in python

Tags: python

I'm sure this has been asked before, but I can't find an answer anywhere...

I have a string that's basically part of an HTML page. It looks a lot like this:

```
body = u'<div class="admonition warning">\n<p class="first admonition-title">Warning</p>\n<p class="last">Read all of this! ALL OF IT!</p>\n</div>\n<div class="section" id="pitfalls-and-common-mistakes">\n<h1>Pitfalls and Common Mistakes<a class="headerlink" href="#pitfalls-and-common-mistakes" title="Permalink to this headline">\xb6</a></h1>\n<p>New and old users alike can run into a pitfall. Below we outline issues that we\nsee frequently as well as explain how to resolve those issues. In the #nginx IRC\nchannel on Freenode, we see these issues frequently.</p>\n<div class="section" id="this-guide-says">\n<h2>This Guide Says<a class="headerlink" href="#this-guide-says" title="Permalink to this headline">\xb6</a></h2>\n<p>The most frequent issue we see happens when someone attempts to just copy and\npaste a configuration snippet from some other guide. Not all guides out there\nare wrong, but a scary number of them are. Even the Linode library has poor\nquality information that some Nginx community members have futily attempted to\ncorrect.</p>\n<p>The Ngx CC Docs were created and reviewed by community members that work\ndirectly with all types of Nginx users. This specific document exists only\nbecause of the volume of common and recurring issues that community members see.</p>\n</div>\n<div class="section" id="my-issue-isn-t-listed">\n<h2>My Issue Isn\'t Listed<a class="headerlink" href="#my-issue-isn-t-listed" title="Permalink to this headline">\xb6</a></h2>\n<p>You don\'t see something in here related to your specific issue. Maybe we didn\'t\npoint you here because of the exact issue you\'re experiencing. Don\'t skim this\npage and assume you were sent here for no reason. You were sent here because\nsomething you did wrong is listed here.</p>\n<p>When it comes to supporting many users on many issues, community members don\'t\nwant to support broken configurations. Fix your configuration before asking for\nhelp. Fix your configuration by reading through this. Don\'t just skim it.</p>\n</div>\n<div class="section" id="root-inside-location-block">\n<h2>Root inside Location Block<a class="headerlink" href="#root-inside-location-block" title="Permalink to this headline">\xb6</a></h2>\n<p>BAD</p>\n<div class="highlight-nginx"><pre>server {\n    server_name www.domain.com;\n      location / {\n          root /var/www/nginx-default/;\n          [...]\n      }\n      location /foo {\n          root /var/www/nginx-default/;\n          [...]\n      }\n      location /bar {\n          root /var/www/nginx-default/;\n          [...]\n      }\n}</pre>\n</div>\n<div class="highlight-nginx"><div class="highlight"><pre><span class="k">def</span> <span class="s">greet(name):</span>\n    <span class="s">print</span> <span class="s">&#39;Hello&#39;,</span> <span class="s">name</span>\n\n<span class="s">greet(&#39;Jack&#39;)</span>\n<span class="s">greet(&#39;Jill&#39;)</span>\n<span class="s">greet(&#39;Bob&#39;)</span>\n</pre></div>\n</div>\n'
```

That's the shortened up version, anyway.

Inside that block is "<div class="highlight-nginx"><pre>" and "</pre></div>" This will appear many times in the same page. Every time it appears, I want to manipulate the text inside of it. I already have the function ready that I want to pump it through. However, I can't figure out how to take the text from it, run it through the function, and stick it back into the string and keep everything else the same.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use an html parser like [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(body)
for div in soup.find_all(class_='highlight-nginx'):
    div.pre.string = my_function(div.pre.string)
```

Comment: for div in soup.find_all(class_='highlight-nginx'): <- On this line, I get TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: It works for me with the example you gave for `body`. try debugging by entering `soup` to see if it is really `None`.

Comment: If I do `soup.find_all('div', 'hilight-nginx')` It finds the correct elements. If I print div.pre.string, I see the content of those elements. However, if I try to set them to anything with `div.pre.text = 'FOOBAR'`, I get `AttributeError: can't set attribute`

Comment: it's `div.pre.string` you need to set, not `div.pre.text`

Comment: Another alternative to BeautifulSoup that I've been playing around with is PyQuery. The syntax is supposed to look more like jQuery so if you're used to manipulating the DOM that way I'd take a look. Both should work well in your scenario so if you have it working with BeautifulSoup I'd just keep it.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is [`re.findall()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) combined with an **ungreedy** regular expression.

Try this (*Note: this is untested*):

```
import re

your_new_text = your_text = '<div class="highlight-nginx"><pre>whatever is inbetween here</pre></div><div class="highlight-nginx"><pre>some more text to change</pre></div><div class="highlight-nginx"><pre>whatever is inbetween here</pre></div>'

pre_text = '<div class="highlight-nginx"><pre>'
post_text = '</pre></div>'
regex = re.compile(r'{pre_text}(.*?){post_text}'.format(pre_text=pre_text,
    post_text=post_text)
# Find all the matches of our regular expression above
list_of_matches = re.findall(your_text)

for text in list_of_matches:
    # We look for an exact match, including the pre and post tags so we're don't perform
    # the wrong sub later on.
    old_text = '{pre_text}{old_string}{post_text}'.format(
        pre_text=pre_text,
        old_string=text,
        post_text=post_text)

    new_text = '{pre_text}{manipulated_text}{post_text}'.format(
        pre_text=pre_text,
        manipulated_text=manipulate_text(text),
        post_text=post_text)

    # We have the old strings and we now replace them with the new strings.
    your_new_text = your_new_text.replace(old_text, new_text)

print(your_new_text)
```

Comment: Don't parse HTML with a regex. It's not possible. Python has an html parser built in http://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html

Comment: Good point. Going to grab some dinner then will write one based on lxml too.